# global modules package node installed with brew Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, npm

Under OSX El Capitan 10.11.2,global modules package(npm -g install [package's name]) node installed with brew can't find module. My code as below

```
"use strict";
require('es6-shim');
const fs = require('fs');
let promise = fs.readFile("example.txt");

promise.then(function(contents) {
    // fulfillment
    console.log(contents);
}, function(err) {
    // rejection
    console.error(err.message);
});

promise.then(function(contents) {
    // fulfillment
    console.log(contents);
});

promise.then(null, function(err) {
    // rejection
    console.error(err.message);
});
```

Run above code results "Cannot find module 'es6-shim'",I tryed to write "NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/" to ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile,but it doesn't work.I know using the third module installed global shoud be called with the absolutely path or using the third module installed based current folder directly,but I want to use the third module according to "require('package's name')" directly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into so many problems with `node` installed like that on MacOS, I decided to move to [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and all my issues about rights/locations/global/... went away and saved my time.

*On top you get a version manage of node which ends to be really helpful when you switch between projects*